# how to make my SharedPreferences object to save data after app closes?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, storing-data

I made an app that her main purpose is to save some sort of information(not important which information right now ), in my app I'm making a `SharedPreferences` object called sp and a `SharedPreferences.Editor` object called editor.

in my `onCreate()` method Im retrieving the stored HashSet like:

```
    Set<String> setFull = sp.getStringSet("SET_FULL", new HashSet<String>());
```

if it's null I get a new HashSet (on first use), and all of the information I need to store Im storing into it as different strings.

I need this Set to be acceptable from all my activities so I use:

```
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
   editor.putStringSet("SET_FULL", setFull);
   editor.apply();            //also tried .commit()
```

in each activity I need that set, so Im retrieving it as the above example.

on the main activity(the one I do all my manipulations on the HashSet),
when the activity is open and alive, I can add to that HashSet and into my `SharedPreferences` items and edit it and everything, and when I travel between my activities I can see it with everything I added and everything is fine, but once I close my app(from my emulator / phone / android studio) when I reopen it, all the data is deleted and I need to add everything all over again.

I tried storing the set back into my editor in 4 different ways:

1:  in my `onCreate()` method:

```
   editor.putStringSet("SET_FULL", setFull);
   editor.apply();            //also tried .commit()
```

2: overriding the method `onDestroy()` in my main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    editor.putStringSet("SET_FULL", setFull);
    editor.apply();
}
```

3: overriding the method `onPause()` in my main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    editor.putStringSet("SET_FULL", setFull);
    editor.apply();
}
```

4: overriding the method `onStop()` in my main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    editor.putStringSet("SET_FULL", setFull);
    editor.apply();
}
```

I also tried putting all 4 options( also tried only 2 or 3 and etc..) together one after the other in my main activity but that also didn't seems to work.

I also tried swapping between .commit() to .apply() (on my `SharedPreferences.Editor` object when I use the `.putStringSet("", set)` on it) but both gave same problem, no more no less.

I didn't got any errors and no warnings or problems( no crashes no nothing ) , it just seems to delete everything once the app closes no matter which way.
I've been looking for solutions for this for the past week, also asked friends( who suggested the same as the internet which was the overriding methods ) but none seems to work, yet everywhere I Read or I ask everyone tells me that a SharedPreferences object should keep the data I Store into it even after my app closes.

Comment: How do you get the preferences - your sp object?

Comment: yes, Im retrieving my HashSet from my sp reference( my SharedPreferences object), and using my SharedPreferences .Editor editor, to put it back in later

Comment: No I mean the code you use to get the sp object. Can you add it?

Comment: I added some of it but here is the full thing:

SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
Set<String> setFull = sp.getStringSet("SET_FULL", new HashSet<String>());

and then Im doing manipulations on the setFull Set and when Im done Im putting it back in as I showed in my question, like this:


                editor.putStringSet("SET_FULL", toReturn);
                editor.apply();         //also tried .commit();

Comment: It looks fine. my guess is that when you close your emulator you delete the app from it. Try to close the app from the emulator and open it again from the emulator without using AndroidStudio. Does it still happen?

Comment: yup, I tried closing and opening it from my android studio and on the emulator itself and on my self phone, on all 3 of them, the app stays(not deleted) but when I open it I need to input everything in from the start

Comment: What happens if you save simple string value and not a StringSet

Comment: How can we tell if the initial `setFull` is not empty or null? Add to your question the block where values are initialised to `setFull` before it is saved to preference.

Comment: void saveDate(String str) {
        //Retrieve the values
        Set<String> setFull = sp.getStringSet("SET_FULL", new HashSet<String>());
        //Set the values
        int numID = getNumOfSelected();
        setFull.add(numID + "" + str);
        editor.putStringSet("SET_FULL", setFull);
        editor.commit();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem thanks to @Henry answer and based on some extra research I've done, I will write the 2 things that solved my problem.
the two solutions are:
the first is based on @Henry answer:    instead of manipulating on the HashSet I get from the SharedPreferences object, copying it(the object itself and not a reference) like that:

```
Set<String> newSet = new HashSet(setFull);
```

the second one is before every-time I put something again inside the SharedPreferences object adding this command:

```
 editor.clear();
```

and that solves my entire problem, it saves the data in the SharedPreferences after the app closes and everything.

thanks to everyone that helped!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the documentation:

> Note that you must not modify the set instance returned by this call. The consistency of the stored data is not guaranteed if you do, nor is your ability to modify the instance at all.

So make sure not to change the `Set<String>` you get back from the `getStringSet()` method. Strange things will happen if you do.

Comment: ok, how will you recommend that I'll act? because I need to dynamically (the user) add more and more items to it and save them into the HashSet?

Comment: You need to copy the returned set to another one. The new set can be changed and then stored back.

Comment: you mean something like:
        Set<String> setFull = sp.getStringSet("SET_FULL", new HashSet<String>());
and then: 
Set<String> newSet = setFull;
and then manipulating everything on newSet

and at the end to store the newSet into my SharedPreferences?

Comment: No. This would not make a copy of the data. `newSet` is just a new reference to the same object.

Comment: so you mean like that?
Set<String> newSet = new HashSet(setFull);
Im new to sets and hashsets, Im not sure if its ok like that?